# Android Studio transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug RemObjects library

Tags: android-studio, android-multidex

After added one more library to project and enabled multiDex, Android studio is started showing this error:

```
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Can't read [MyApp\libs\com.remobjects.sdk.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Can't process class [com/remobjects/sdk/helpers/Logger.class] (Method must be overridden in [proguard.classfile.attribute.SourceFileAttribute] if ever called))
Error:java.io.IOException: Can't read [MyApp\libs\com.remobjects.sdk.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Can't process class [com/remobjects/sdk/helpers/Logger.class] (Method must be overridden in [proguard.classfile.attribute.SourceFileAttribute] if ever called))
Error:java.io.IOException: Can't process class [com/remobjects/sdk/helpers/Logger.class] (Method must be overridden in [proguard.classfile.attribute.SourceFileAttribute] if ever called)
Error:java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Method must be overridden in [proguard.classfile.attribute.SourceFileAttribute] if ever called
```

gradle console:

```
:MyApp:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug
:MyApp:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug FAILED
```

build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
```

buildscript:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

I'm working on three applications and only this one is problematic. One app is only upgraded version of other and upgraded app generating apk file sucessfully. I tried to copy gradle file and edit it, but without any luck. 
I already tried editing proguard.cfg with all possible commands I found on internet but error is still there.

Tomorrow I have to publish new verison and I can't build APK..

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong.

Minimal SDK version in Manifest was set to 15 and after I changed it to 21, APK was successfully generated.